# Manipulating data after gridview query in Yii

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a Gridview with data from a table which normally is ok as it is.
But in some cases i have to manipulate the data, and i can't just do it from the query as there are many different cases and requires complex calculations.

Example:
base data loaded from db:

```
date        price   buy_price
2019-05-01  15.75   10
2019-05-02  20.15   10.50
```

same data which passed through complex calculations

```
date        price   buy_price
2019-05-01  3.75   3
2019-05-02  4.70   3.10
```

I would like to use GridView cause the ajax filtering and sorting are really useful.

How can i manipulate the data AFTER the query the Gridview executes based on the DataProvider?

Comment: If you want to do some manipulations on data **after** query was performed, sorting and filtering may not work correctly, since it is done on query level, so before your manipulations (different values will be used for filtering than displayed by grid view).

Comment: Yes, but the fields on which the user will be able to filter will be the only fields that won't be processed (for example the date). Thanks for the advise anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example in [Yii2 Documentation about GridvViews](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets#grid-view) says, you can manipulate any column to your need in the following way:

```
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    // Simple columns defined by the data contained in $dataProvider.
    'data',
    [
        'attribute' => 'price',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->getValue();  // Here you can manipulate the data as you wish.
        },
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'buy_price',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return $model->buy_price * 2;  //Here you can manipulate the data as you wish.
        },
    ],
],]);
```

After manipulating data, you can still use the sort or the ajax filtering.

Comment: Can work. The question is: can the attributes be manipulated inside the callback function? Cause for every model i would have some values i need to multiply or divide to. In your example you use 3 and 2, in my case i have to calculate that numbers and it will be used on more than one model attribute.

Comment: From what you said, I suppose there is some sort of function, such as `$model->getValueOfSomething()`. In this case you can call that getter function in the anonymous function.